# Heroku custom subdomain not accessible

Tags: node.js, heroku, dns, subdomain, cname

I've setup a NodeJS app on Heroku and it can be accessed properly by the randomly generated Heroku url: https://blooming-castle-48256.herokuapp.com/

However, now i'm trying to have the application accessible through a subdomain. I've followed the steps outlined in the Heroku documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) and i'm still not getting not able to access the app from my custom subdomain.

In the Heroku dashboard, i've added my custom subdomain to be `lorem-ipsum.mydomain.me` and Heroku provided a DNS Target of `lorem-ipsum.mydomain.me.herokudns.com`

In my cpanel Advanced Zone Editor for my domain, i've created a CNAME record with a name of `lorem-ipsum.mydomain.me.`, a TTL of 1200, and a record of `lorem-ipsum.mydomain.me.herokudns.com`

When I try accessing `lorem-ipsum.mydomain.me` in my browser, I get a error saying:

> lorem-ipsum.mydomain.me’s server DNS address could not be found.

**Troubleshooting I've Done**

Using an online DNS checker to check whether the nameservers for the subdomain have been propagated, I discovered that it correctly displays `lorem-ipsum.mydomain.me.herokudns.com.` as the nameserver for the subdomain.

When I go to my terminal and execute the command `host lorem-ipsum.robertcooper.me`, I received the following error:

> Host lorem-ipsum.mydomain.me not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

How can I resolve this issue and have my subdomain properly display my Heroko web app?

**Additional Information**

My hosting and domain registration for `mydomain.me` are both with Namecheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing your local DNS cache.
You can find the method for many different operating systems [here](https://www.whatsmydns.net/flush-dns.html)

Comment: That fixed it for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, with a domain and subdomain (registered with Ionos) pointing to different locations.

In my case the main domain `example.com` went to a Carrd landing page, while `cloud.example.com` went to a Heroku app.

I followed the steps in the question above, providing the custom DNS target from Heroku, but it would not work until I enabled SSL certificates in Heroku for that dyno (that means a basic dyno as a minimum, which is now a paid service).

So, in summary, Heroku needed SSL enabled.